# How to work with quickbase queries

Tags: php, quickbase

Can any one told me that how can i add ,Edit or delete records in quickbase using the URL only 
like i have a URL for api_doquery i.e.

https://www.quickbase.com/db/bad8qdsuy?a=api_doquery&qid=98

But i want to add,edit or delete the records so please provide me the way to do that for add,edit or delete with my form data  ,

I have found this URL https:///db/57pa5vjf?act=API_AddRecord&_fnm_second_year=1776&_fid_8=changed but didnt get the meanig of this one ,

So please tell me that how can i do this type of things in Quickbase...

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. You can add, edit and delete records with commands like this
https://www.quickbase.com/db/nnnnnnnnn?a=api_AddRecord where nnnnnnnnn is the unique id of the table. If you are deleting or editting a record, it is more like https://www.quickbase.com/db/nnnnnnnnn?a=api_EditRecord&rid=mm where mm is the record id. Then you have name value pairs like _fid_20=95 -- that says set field 20 equal to 95.

You will also need to authenticate with a ticket, or with a username and password. If the application requires apptokens (this varies from app to app) you may also have to supply an app token. There is a lot more information on QUickBase help.

Comment: could you please write down the query over here so that i can follow them actually i m totally new for quickbase i am a developer with core php functionality and have knowledge about mysql and mssql but quickbase is totally new for me so plz give me a reply with proper syntax ....for eding and deleting a record.